# How to access object for id

Tags: objective-c

Hiho code-friends,

I created a NSMutableDictionary "_favDictionary" with picture-data inside. I am getting the key from my current cell from a collection-view, which contains an integer named "key".

```
FLAMainCell *cell = (FLAMainCell *) sender.view;
NSUInteger *key = cell.key;

NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)key];
_favDictionary[inStr] = storeImage;  


- (UIImage *)getFavouriteImages:(NSInteger)index{
    return _favDictionary[index];
}
```

I am a beginner in objective-c and I could not find a possibility to access my dictionary with an integer value like in my method "getFavouriteImages". The error I am getting says "NSMutableDictionary doesn't respond to ObjectAtIndexedSubscript".

Can someone tell me how I can access my dictionary via an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you are indexing only by integers, you could use a `NSArray`.

If you want to use a `NSDictionary`, you don't have to convert integers to strings, you can use `NSNumber` instead.

```
FLAMainCell *cell = (FLAMainCell *) sender.view;
NSUInteger *key = cell.key;

NSNumber *inNumber = @(key);
_favDictionary[inNumber] = storeImage;  

- (UIImage *)getFavouriteImages:(NSInteger)index{
    return _favDictionary[@(index)];
}
```

If you want to use strings, then you have to convert `index` to a `NSString` too, before indexing:

```
- (UIImage *)getFavouriteImages:(NSInteger)index{
    NSString *stringIndex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(index)];
    return _favDictionary[stringIndex];
}
```

Comment: awh my god ... thanks! I wasn't able to do smth for over an hour when I realised, that the solution is so easy. 

I found a way with the function to access the dictionary with integers:

    NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)key];